# How do I change the starting point of an SVG line animation?

Tags: css, animation, svg, svg-animate

I am new to working with SVG and animation.  I am trying to simply make an animation where a hexagon draws itself starting from the topmost point.  However, the animation starts from middle right point.  What is the best solution to solve this problem?

```css
.root {
  background-color: black;
}
.shape {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #61fbde;
    stroke-width: 3px;
    stroke-dasharray: 1300px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1300px;
    animation: move 3s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes move {
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="root">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="129.204 94.714 359.102 415.224" width="355.1" height="411.22"><defs><path class="shape" d="M485.31 197.76v206.12L307.76 506.94 130.2 403.88V197.76L307.76 95.71l177.55 102.05z" id="a"/></defs><use xlink:href="#a" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#61fbde"/></svg>

</div>
```

Comment: Stroke animations always start at the beginning of the path....so change the path! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to change the value of the d attribute so that the path begins where the animation need to begin

```css
.root {
  background-color: black;
}
.shape {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #61fbde;
    stroke-width: 3px;
    stroke-dasharray: 1300px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1300px;
    animation: move 3s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes move {
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="root">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="129.204 94.714 359.102 415.224" width="355.1" height="411.22"><defs><path class="shape" d="
M307.76 95.71
L485.31 197.76
v206.12
L307.76 506.94 130.2 403.88
V197.76
L307.76 95.71
z" id="a"/></defs><use xlink:href="#a" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#61fbde"/></svg>

</div>
```

Comment: Why did you have to remove l177.55 102.05 from the path?

Comment: I had to rewrite the `d` attribute so that the path began where you wanted. I've recalculated  `l177.55 102.05` because I needed absolute coordinates in order to start the path here

Comment: d="M485.31 197.76v206.12L307.76 506.94 130.2 403.88V197.76L307.76 95.71**l177.55 102.05**z" can also be written like so: d="M485.31 197.76v206.12L307.76 506.94 130.2 403.88V197.76L307.76 95.71**L307.76 95.71**z"

Comment: "You will need to..." No, OP doesn't "need to" change the `d` attribute. Please state so when you're merely giving *an* answer

Answer (score 3):

*Another idea that allows you to start an animation from anywhere without redrawing the shape*

Can be used for `stroke-dasharray` line drawing animation

Move animation start point with `stroke-dashoffset`

The total line length is `1232px`

- Completely hidden line -`stroke-dasharray = "0, 1232"`
- The line is visible - `stroke-dasharray =" 1232, 0 "`

Therefore, for line drawing animations, it is necessary to increase the stroke length from zero to a maximum of -`1232px`

```
@keyframes move {
     0% {
        stroke-dasharray: 0, 1232;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dasharray: 1232,0;
    }
}
```

- In order to move the starting point of the animation to the top of
  the hexagon

  `stroke-dashoffset="205.3"`

```css
.root {
  width:25%;
  height:25%;
  background-color: black;
}
.shape {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #61fbde;
    stroke-width: 5px;
    stroke-dasharray: 0,1232px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 205.3px;
    animation: move 3s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes move {
     0% {
        stroke-dasharray: 0, 1232;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dasharray: 1232,0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="root">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="129.204 94.714 359.102 415.224" >
<defs>
 <path class="shape" d="M485.31 197.76v206.12L307.76 506.94 130.2 403.88V197.76L307.76 95.71l177.55 102.05z" id="a" />

 </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#a"  /> 
  </svg>

</div>
```

*Using this approach, you can start the animation from anywhere, for example, from the bottom vertex of the hexagon*

Move the start point of the line animation to the bottom of the hexagon `stroke-dashoffset: 821.3px;`

```css
.root {
width:25%;
height:25%;
  background-color: black;
}
.shape {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #61fbde;
    stroke-width: 5px;
    stroke-dasharray: 0,1232px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 821.3px;
    animation: move 3s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes move {
     0% {
        stroke-dasharray: 0, 1232;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dasharray: 1232,0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="root">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="129.204 94.714 359.102 415.224" >
<defs>
 <path class="shape" d="M485.31 197.76v206.12L307.76 506.94 130.2 403.88V197.76L307.76 95.71l177.55 102.05z" id="a" />

 </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#a"  /> 
  </svg>

</div>
```

An example of drawing from a single point with two symmetrical lines

```css
.root {
width:25%;
height:25%;
  background-color: black;
}
.shape {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #61fbde;
    stroke-width: 5px;
    stroke-dasharray: 0,1232px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 821.3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="129.204 94.714 359.102 415.224" >
<defs>
 <path class="shape" d="M485.31 197.76v206.12L307.76 506.94 130.2 403.88V197.76L307.76 95.71l177.55 102.05z" id="a" >
  <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="4s" values="0,616 0,616;0,0  1232,0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
 </path>

 </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#a"  /> 
  </svg>

</div>
```

Hexagon  animation example with dicsrete drawing

```css
.root {
width:25%;
height:25%;
  background-color: black;
}
.shape {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #61fbde;
    stroke-width: 5px;
    stroke-dasharray: 0,1232px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 205.3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="129.204 94.714 359.102 415.224" >
<defs>
 <path class="shape" d="M485.31 197.76v206.12L307.76 506.94 130.2 403.88V197.76L307.76 95.71l177.55  102.05z" id="a" >
    <animate
   attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   dur="3s"
   values="
   0,1232;
   205.3,1027;
   410.6,822;
   616,616;
   822,410.6;
   1027.3,205.3;
   1232,0"
   calcMode="discrete"
   repeatCount="indefinite" />
 </path>

 </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#a"  /> 
  </svg>

</div>
```

Comment: Way better than suggesting changing the starting point of the path. +1